# JSchException verify: False C# .NET Scp SSH

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, scp, sharpssh

I want to connect to remote server to upload some files via SCP/SSH.

I am using SharpSSH for this but it doesnt work.

Everytime the ScpClint wants to connect i get the JSchException verify: False.

Here is my code:

```
Scp scpClient = new Scp();
scpClient.To(@"C:localPath", "hostIP", "/var/...", sshUser, sshPwd);
```

Does anybody an have any suggestions on how to fix this problem? Maybe another library? I also tried Renci.SshNet but there I can connect or it doesn't give any errors, but no matter what I try to upload nothing is to find on the Server.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the library are you using? That code is fairly old and unmaintained. My usual recommendation is to try SSHNet since that's a much more solid library, written for .NET, but you said you've already tried that. Perhaps it's a problem on the remote side if you cannot connect with either of the libraries?